# How to log all file access in Windows before login?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, performance, windows-update

I am trying to troubleshoot/fix a 30 minute boot time (i.e., the time between power being applied
and the login screen appearing).  All diagnostics (CPU, HDD, RAM) seem fine, so I simply suspect
a bug in the interaction of Windows with hardware drivers/firmware.

The HDD bottlenecks almost every process on this computer so, to understand what is happening
here, I wish I could get a log of all file accesses (just like the "Disk" tab in
"Resource Monitor", but I want it before the system lets me do anything).  My gut belief,
though I really have no evidence, is that Windows is processing/rewriting some update files
(or the full OS), because it sees some danger of a faulty boot corrupting everything.

I have looked at the "ntbtlog" file and many of Windows' logs/timestamps and everything indicates
that drivers are all loaded quickly with Windows up and running within the first minute, but I
simply can't track what causes the 30 minute delay...a time log of all file accesses with some rough byte counts would give me the bigger picture.  Is there a way to get a log like this before
login?

Comment: Try instead MSCONFIG and curtail the number of items allowed to start. This will normally work better.

Comment: @John I don't see why that would be better, I have to guess which services to stop out of hundreds.  I have tried approaches like yours already (and am already using "selective startup") and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @John One problem is that Windows Update cannot be stopped even when things say it is stopped.

Comment: I don't think you can list files pre boot.  Perhaps at this point try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.

Comment: And disk access times for a big file once it's up seems normal? Also may be worth checking SMART. Is this HDD or SSD?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen HDD.  Yes, all seems normal once I get past the 30 minutes. I have checked SMART and found no problems.  I am really confused and frustrated.

Comment: Just a wild guess - I once observed such a very similar effect when a certain USB stick was plugged in into the computer of a friend. Took us over an hour until we found out that simply pulling the stick out solved the issue.

Comment: Perhaps you can post screenshot of CrystalDiskInfo or similar so we can see raw SMART values. Just to rule out hard drive.

Comment: @DocBrown This might be related because I have 2 bootable partitions on my hard disk.  Any idea why a second boot method would cause this bug?

Comment: @bobuhito: not the slightest.